# How to extract nested object from binance websocket response

Tags: node.js, binance

I'm befuddled by Nodejs (v19.8.1). I'm trying to extract the closing price of BNBBUSD using Binance's Websocket API.

The Json object returned by Binance is this

```
{   e: 'kline',   
    E: 1680191074480,   
    s: 'BNBBUSD',   
  k: {
    t: 1680191040000,
    T: 1680191099999,
    s: 'BNBBUSD',
    i: '1m',
    f: 202374774,
    L: 202374788,
    o: '316.20000000',
    c: '316.30000000',
    h: '316.30000000',
    l: '316.20000000',
    v: '2.52200000',
    n: 15,
    x: false,
    q: '797.49570000',
    V: '0.39300000',
    Q: '124.30590000',
    B: '0'   } 
}
```

I want to extract "c" which is the closing price of the tick.

I have this.

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import util from 'util';

const url = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws';

const ws = new WebSocket(url);

ws.on('message', (data, isBinary) => {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data['k']);
  const o = data['k'];
  console.log(o['s']);    //Getting error here but i'm not sure why
});

ws.on('open', () => {
  const bnbbusd = JSON.stringify({ method: 'SUBSCRIBE', params: [ 'bnbbusd@kline_1m' ], id: 1 });
  ws.send(bnbbusd);
  console.log(`< ${bnbbusd}`);
});
```

I'm getting an error on console.log(o['s']); With this error message, `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 's')`

I've also tried accessing the 'c' value using data['k']['c'] but getting the same error. I'm not sure where i've gone wrong...

Additional information:

data['k'] returns the following

```
{
  t: 1680191820000,
  T: 1680191879999,
  s: 'BNBBUSD',
  i: '1m',
  f: 202375679,
  L: 202375697,
  o: '316.00000000',
  c: '316.00000000',
  h: '316.00000000',
  l: '315.90000000',
  v: '24.74600000',
  n: 19,
  x: false,
  q: '7817.56610000',
  V: '3.04700000',
  Q: '962.85200000',
  B: '0'
}
```

Comment: yes it does. it shows { t: 1680191820000, T: 1680191879999, ..., c: '316.00000000', ... }

Comment: const b1 = data['k'];
  console.log(typeof(b1));  // object

Comment: is it possble that data dont always contain property k

Comment: it always returns with property k though... getting stumped on this. the python version that I've coded works fine.

Comment: i checked on the browser. the initial subscription gives back `{result: null, id: 1}`. that's why you get errors. after that it keeps sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [this](https://github.com/binance-us/binance-us-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#subscribe-to-a-stream) initial subscription to a stream sends back the response in the format

```js
{
  "result": null,
  "id": 1
}
```

now this gave errors because the fields you are looking for are not there. Notice the first `console.log` in the below snippet

```js
const url = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws';

const ws = new WebSocket(url);

ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
  const bnbbusd = JSON.stringify({ method: 'SUBSCRIBE', params:['bnbbusd@kline_1m' ], id: 1 });
  ws.send(bnbbusd);
  console.log(`< ${bnbbusd}`);
});

ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  console.log(data)

  const o = data['k'];     
  console.log(o['s']);
});
```

so what i did was just ignore the initial subscription response by doing an `if` check and returning

```js
const url = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws';

const ws = new WebSocket(url);

ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
  const bnbbusd = JSON.stringify({ method: 'SUBSCRIBE', params:['bnbbusd@kline_1m' ], id: 1 });
  ws.send(bnbbusd);
  console.log(`< ${bnbbusd}`);
});

ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);

  // ignore the first message
  if (data?.result === null && data?.id === 1) {
    return;
  }

  const o = data['k'];     
  console.log(o['s']);
});
```

Comment: Oh my! You are right! I kept looking at the output of data['k'] and it never occurred that Binance is also returning { "result": null, "id": 1 }. Thanks again and I'll be making some modifications to address the data?.id === 1 as id will be incremented with more crypto streams.

Comment: Yeah sure. It's easy to do modifications when you identify where things can go wrong